# Android app too slow

Tags: trello, android

Am I the only one who's Trello front page on the android app never fully loads? The loading animation never seems to stop, it's loading for an hour now. Also I used to have a couple of boards on the Trello website that I didn't have the need for anymore and I removed them, but they still appear in the android app.

I like Trello, a LOT. I would really love to be able to use it on my smartphone.

I have a fairly fast internet speed on my smartphone, both wireless and network but it doesn't help. 
My android version is 2.3.5.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about a native Android app. It belongs at [android.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this sometimes with the Trello Android App.  I simply close and re-open the app and it usually syncs the second time. Log out and then log back in if reloading the app didn't work.

You may need to make sure the app has access to the network as some background apps (like battery savers or task killers*) can block network access when they should not.

Once your app finally syncs your boards list should be correct.

- I do NOT recommend using task killers. I just know some people do and they can sometimes interfere with program operation in unexpected ways.

Comment: Reinstalling the app did the trick!

Comment: @Vedran Great news.  Re-installing can clear things up too. Thank You for letting us know!

Comment: FWIW, the team is working on performance issues for the next release. We'll keep this in mind!

Comment: I just logged out, then back in, and all of my organizations/boards are as they should be. It would be awesome if the refresh completely sync'd up your stuff